# IBM Worklight: iPad Splash Screen in iOS 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight Consumer Edition 5.0.6.1 with latest interim fix and have the following questions regarding splash screen:

(1) When my app is running on iPad simulator (iOS 7), there is a black space at the top of the splash screen. Please see the screenshot below. 
[There is no such problem when running on iPhone (iOS 7)]

(2) I have turned on "AutoHideSplashScreen" as "true" in config.xml for iOS. And there is logic inside my js to hide the splash screen. However, I discover that before the logic inside my js is executed, the splash screen was hidden already. 
[There is no such problem for Android]

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

[image]

===========================================================================

**EDIT**: For the iPad splash screen problem, I have done the following tests in iOS Simulator (iOS 7.0.3). Please note that you need to manually delete the app after a trial, clean the project and build again or otherwise the change sometimes will not be effective.

Trial 1: Specify launch image for 768 x 1004 (iOS 6.1 and Prior) and 768 x 1024 (iOS 7):

> > Result: At the beginning, it takes the image for iOS7 (no black space at the top). After 1 second, it takes the image for iOS 6.1 and Prior (there is a black space at the top). So, the splash screen was "flashed" and the black space suddenly appear for this transition.

Trial 2: Specify launch image for 768 x 1004 (iOS 6.1 and Prior) and does not specify 768 x 1024 (iOS 7):

> > Result: There is black space at the top always in launch screen.

Trial 3: Does not specify launch image for 768 x 1004 (iOS 6.1 and Prior) and specify 768 x 1024 (iOS 7):

> > Result: There is whole black screen for around 1 second. And afterwards, the launch screen shows normally without black space at the top.

So, it seems that the launch screen always loads in the following sequence:

iOS 7 --> iOS 6.1 and Prior --> Start the app

Comment: I think the issue is that the status bar has both black TEXT and black BACKGROUND. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your own Splash Screen image, with the correct sizes recommended by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

It seems the default Worklight splash screen does not have a matching size.

In XCode, in the General settings for your project, scroll until you see the list of Launch Images. You should see in the right column some images with the words "No image selected". Make sure there is a match for each for those images.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have already used the correct size recommeneded by Apple but the problem still occurred. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Make sure all of the required images are installed and valid. I've opened a defect at IBM to look into strange "flash" of a black bar.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I confirm that all images are being matched in "Launch Images". See if you can also reproduce the same result after defining all images.

Answer (score 0):

Re 2:

- There is no point in comparing to Android...
- Worklight utilizes its own splash image mechanism, so the `AutoHideSplashScreen` flag is of no use; you cannot control when to hide the splash image, at this time.

Re 1:

- Will be investigated.

Comment: Hi Idan, may I know if you have any update on Item 1? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see the answer by Nathan Hazout.